# Calculate a voltage drop from power drawn (not current)

Tags: voltage

A long time ago, I studied the basics of electrical engineering, where I learned the formula to calculate the voltage drop in a single-phase circuit for a certain current drawn.

\$ \Delta U = 2 ~ \rho ~ \frac{L}{S} ~ \cos{\varphi} + X ~ L ~ \sin{\varphi} ~ I \$

With \$\rho\$ for the resistivity of cable, \$L\$ for its length, \$S\$ for its section, \$\varphi\$ for the phase shift (not sure of the translation), \$X\$ being \$0.08 ~ m \Omega/m\$ (to be honest I don't have a real understanding of this one), and \$I\$ for the drawn current.

But now, I wonder: if I design a circuit, I know the power of devices I will connect to it, but **as far I know** (and here I guess I have a partially wrong understanding of the concepts involved), the drawn current of the devices will depend of the voltage they receive (I mean, \$P = U \times I\$ (ignoring power factor etc)), and so the \$I\$ will vary according to \$\Delta U\$.

So, for instance, if I have a 1000W device to connect to a 230V source 500m away, how can I calculate a voltage drop for a given wire section? My guess is that I have a limited understanding of the relation between these formulas, so would you have any advice on this? Or should I just calculate the current as if it had the nominal voltage (so just replacing \$I\$ with \$\frac{P}{U}\$ in the formula)?

I hope I'm not too unclear, thank you in advance!

PS: This is my first post here, so I hope I didn't mess up the post or the tags. Don't hesitate to correct me if needed! :)

Comment: Power is calculated from (U-Udrop) x I = P. Udrop = R x I...

Comment: I see, but what I meant was that I'm trying to calculate the voltage drop by knowing not the current but the power of the device at the end of the line. So I was wondering how to calculate the current drawn, since this implies knowing the voltage (and that makes the problem a bit recursive, since the voltage at the end of the line depends precisely on the current drawn).

Comment: As an example, let's say I have a 100W lamp, which would draw about 0.43A under 230V. But assuming a voltage drop of 10V, how can I know the drawn current? And here, my understanding of electricity finds its limits. Should I just use the voltage at start of line to calculate the drawn current (so suppose it will be 0.43A even if there is not 230V at the end of line)? I guess it is not that simple...

Comment: If it was a resistive load with DC voltages: (U-Udrop) x I = P, I x R = Udrop -> UI - RI^2 = P -> Find I -> back to I x R = Udrop

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: So to get Udrop in the first instance, we have to ignore the resistivity of the cable, right? I found [a webpage](https://www.jcalc.net/voltage-drop-calculator-as3008) saying that the current is calculated as "I = P / (U x cos(phi)" (so the usual formula), but then P is only the power of the load, and it ignores the power dissipated by the cable itself I guess. Or does it all come down to the same thing? Sorry, I probably just don't have the intuition of maths behind this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to calculate the voltage drop by knowing not the current but the power of the device at the end of the line.

If the load is resistive, or has power factor correction  (PFC), the calculation is straightforward.

Power Factor Correction is a technique that ensures that the instantaneous current drawn by the power supply of an electronic device is approximately proportional to the instantaneous voltage at the input terminals of that device.

$$i \propto v_{load}$$

When that is the case, we can use the common formula for power in a *resistive* load, to relate the RMS voltage across the terminals of such a device (\$V_{load}\$) and RMS current through the device, to the power.

$$P_{load}=V_{load}I$$

If we know the total resistance of the wires, counted in both directions (\$R_{wires}\$), we can calculate the voltage drop in the wires as

$$V_{wires}=IR_{wires}$$

The voltage at the device is related to the mains voltage by

$$V_{mains}=V_{wires} +V_{load}$$

Rearranging these equations, we have

$$V_{wires} = V_{mains}-V_{load}$$

$$I=\frac{V_{wires}}{R_{wires}}$$

$$V_{load} = \frac{P_{load}}{I}$$

Putting them all together gives

$$V_{wires} =V_{mains}-\frac{P_{load}}{\frac{V_{wires}}{R_{wires}}} =V_{mains}-\frac{P_{load}R_{wires}}{V_{wires}}$$

Multiplying both sides by \$V_{wires}\$ gives the quadratic equation

$$V_{wires}^2 = V_{wires}V_{mains}-P_{load}R_{wires}$$

Solving that quadratic equation for \$V_{wires}\$ gives the voltage drop in the wires!

$$V_{wires} = \frac{V_{mains} - \sqrt{V_{mains}^2 - 4P_{load}R_{wires}}}{2}$$

---

Edit:

> I was mainly wondering how could someone determine calculatively the good cable size to use to power a device with a low enough voltage drop, as it depends on the current drawn, which itself depends on the end-of-line voltage. Like, to calculate the right cable size to power a 5000W device with a power generator which is 500 meters away. I guess it's a common question in electrical engineering, but I couldn't figure it out. How do real-life people solve this kind of problems? Do they have to do trial-and-error until they find a good value?

You can *start* with an acceptable voltage drop in the wires, and use the formula:

$$R_{wires} = \frac{V_{wires}V_{mains}-V_{wires}^2}{P_{load}}$$

to calculate the maximum wire resistance that would give your that acceptable voltage drop. Knowing the maximum resistance, and the length, you could look up in a table the minimum wire size you need.

For example, if you want a maximum voltage drop of 10 V, and your mains voltage is 230 V, then your wires must have a resistance of less than

$$R_{wires} = \frac{(10)(2300)-10^2}{5000} = 440 m\Omega$$

Since you have 500 meters of *cable*, you have 1000 meters of *wire*. So you need wire with a maximum resistance of 440 \$m\Omega\$ per km.

[This table](https://www.kbe-elektrotechnik.com/en/service/awg-table/) shows that copper wire AWG #1 has 470 \$m\Omega\$ per km, so you would need AWG #0 or better, (or an appropriate equivalent in another wire gauge). This will be pretty heavy and expensive, and it invites the question of whether 1 (or 2) transformers and a higher voltage transmission line might not offer a more economical solution.

---

What happens if the power factor of the load is NOT 1? It would be nice if we could simply insert the power factor into our quadratic equation in one or two places. I have not worked out the math, but I believe the solution will not be that simple. Perhaps if I get the time, or someone else has the time, one of us could give a more definite answer.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, but this asserts that the current won't change proportionally with the voltage drop, right?

Comment: @MichaelMarx If your device draws constant power regardless of voltage, as perhaps a computer might, then it will draw MORE current as the voltage drops. A heater, on the other hand, may draw LESS current when the voltage drops. What happens will depend on the type of load you have.

Comment: @MichaelMarx. I may have misunderstood the question in your comment. For a fixed length of wire, i.e. a fixed wire resistance, the voltage drop in the wire will be proportional to the current through the wire -- a direct application of Ohm's Law. But if the length of the wire varies, a longer wire may result in more current drawn, as discussed in my previous comment.

Comment: No, you've understood my question. :) In fast, I was mainly wondering how could someone determine calculatively the good cable size to use to power a device with a low enough voltage drop, as it depends on the current drawn, which itself depends on the end-of-line voltage. Like, to calculate the right cable size to power a 5000W device with a power generator which is 500 meters away. I guess it's a common question in electrical engineering, but I couldn't figure it out. How do real-life people solve this kind of problems? Do they have to do trial-and-error until they find a good value?

Comment: I have added an intermezzo edit to my answer that may help.

Comment: Oooh, so I think I finally got it (I was thinking of it the other way round I guess). Thank you so much! :)